# Irreducible fraction

Tags: arithmetic

Prove that
$$
\frac{2}{99},\frac{3}{98},...,\frac{97}{4},\frac{98}{3},\frac{99}{2}%
$$
are irreducible.

My attempt is:
if $a/b$ is irreducible, than $\left(  a,b\right)  =1$. Now, I choose
$a=k,k=2,3,...,99$ and $b=101-k$, hence we need to show that
$$
\left(  k,101-k\right)  =1,~k=2,3,...,99.
$$
Since $\left(  a,b\right)  =\left(  b,a\right)  $, it is sufficient to show
that $\left(  k,101-k\right)  =1$ for all $k=2,3,...,49$. I know that
$$
\left(  a,b\right)  =\left\{
\begin{array}
[c]{cc}%
\left(  a-b,b\right)  , & a>b\\
\left(  a,b-a\right)  , & a<b
\end{array}
\right.  .
$$

If $k=2,3,4,...,49,$ then $101-k>k$ and
$$
\left(  k,101-k\right)  =\left(  k,101-2k\right)  =...
$$
Here is where I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Prove it by conversing the proof

Comment: You can assume they are reducible and then prove it false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More simply, if $k$ and $101-k$ had a common  factor $d>1$, would divide $k+101-k=101$. This can't happen, as $101$ is prime.